# Grpc System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed

Tags: .net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-2.0, google-cloud-pubsub

When stopping a service using Pub/Sub and running on Google App Engine, the following stacktrace is received.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef
    at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.ChannelSafeHandle.CreateCall
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.CreateNativeCall
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.Initialize
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.StartDuplexStreamingCall
    at Grpc.Core.Calls.AsyncDuplexStreamingCall[TRequest,TResponse]
    at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.AsyncDuplexStreamingCall[TRequest,TResponse]
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.InterceptingCallInvoker.AsyncDuplexStreamingCall[TRequest,TResponse]
    at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.Subscriber.SubscriberClient.StreamingPull
    at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiBidirectionalStreamingCall.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<Create>b__0
    at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiBidirectionalStreamingCall`2.Call
    at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberServiceApiClientImpl.StreamingPull
    at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClientImpl.SingleChannel.<StartAsync>d__18.MoveNext
```

For the project we use ASP.NET Core with [this](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/index.html) library to handle the Pub/Sub communication. The issue is not present while debugging locally, using the Pub/Sub emulator. Therefore, we assume that it has something to do with the way App Engine phases out the docker container? Only catching the exception will not be a satisfying solution as we risk leaving handled messages unacknowledged. Can we in any way fix this issue so we can stop our service in a safe way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be related to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9670 Do you think you can provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I found out it was my own code. I have posted an answer, should others make the same mistake as I did.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the error was within my code... I am using an IHostedService in ASP.NET Core and stopping the subscriber with the following approach:

`cancellationToken.Register(async () => { await subscriber.StopAsync(token) })`

However this will fire and forget and will therefore not wait for the client to stop properly before disposing the objects inside the service provider. As I used *Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore* (which is registered in the service provider and uses Grpc) to log some useful debug statements, it is able to be disposed before end usage.